# Refactoring Computed Properties on Ember.js 1.13

Tags: ember.js

I was able to upgrade most of my Ember.js project to 1.13 after having some issues [along the way](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-js-1-13-nothing-displayed-on-each-even-though-i-can-see-it-on-the-ember-inspector/8237), but now I can't wrap my head around the following deprecated code:

```
filteredPosts: function(){...}.property('var1','var2','var3')
```

When I enable it, the only notice that I receive is:

> Uncaught TypeError: controllerClass.proto is not a function.

Noting that **ComputedPropertyPrototype.get** is the only useful information coming from the Stack Trace.

After researching around, I only found [this](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-reducecomputed-ember-arraycomputed) concerning the deprecation, so I wanted to know how such code would be refactored into the native array methods or into anything that allows the same behavior.

Also, my apologies as I unfortunately cannot post an extra link to the specific file due to being a new user, so if you want to see the complete project you can head to github.com/Deovandski/Fakktion.

Comment: I'm not really getting what the error is here. Are you having issues updating to the [new computed property syntax](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html)?

Comment: After following Daniel's answer and seeing your link, I did not had any problems. What happened is that the errors and deprecation warnings led me astray from finding the real solution. Hence, I decided to ask about it on StackOverflow and soon enough people helped me out :)

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. We're just helping out the Ember community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filteredPosts: function(){...}.property('var1','var2','var3')
```

should become:

```
filteredPosts: Ember.computed('var1', 'var2', 'var3', function() {
...
});
```

It's because prototype extensions are discouraged in recent versions of Ember and seems like you've encountered a problem related to prototype extensions. It'd be best if you create a demo of this issue, but `Ember.computed` should just work.